# PDFKit & PyPDF2 - Could not read malformed PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, pdfkit, pypdf

I am facing the an issue with pdf files generated from pdfkit.from_file(filename, 'w+'). Where filename is a html file.

After generating the PDF files from the html files, the are merged with the following code:

```
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for pdf in input_files: merger.append(pdf)
    merger.write(output_stream) merger.close()
```

This is wher I hit the error:

```
File "/home/finrpt/finrpt/finrpt_py/htm_gen.py", line 193, in pdf_cat 
    input = PdfFileReader(f)
  File "/home/finrpt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "/home/finrpt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1697, in read
    line = self.readNextEndLine(stream)
  File "/home/finrpt/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1937, in readNextEndLine
    raise utils.PdfReadError("Could not read malformed PDF file")
  PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Could not read malformed PDF file
```

Any advice or pointers to this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A PDF document is malformed when it doesn’t observe the basic structure of a PDF document. The problem could be in the html->pdf conversion process.